# SQL setting a variable to a stored procedure return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently studying stored procedures and I saw that if i want do declare a variable and set a value to it (from the user defined procedure) the syntax is like

```
DECLARE @count int
EXEC @count = CurrentEmployees
```

Isn't there syntax strange?... I mean in the other programming languages (and yes i know that sql is a query not a programming language) you would write the variable on your left and the value on the right. Should be something like

```
DECLARE @count int
@count=EXEC CurrentEmployees
```

Any ideas why the syntax is like this?
P.S. in my example CurrentEmployees is a user defined procedure.

Comment: Google `RETURN VALUE` from SQL Server stored procedures and `OUTPUT PARAMETERS`.

Comment: @M.Ali yea i get the concept... my question is why the syntax is so confusing

Comment: @john . . . (1) Not everyone thinks the syntax is confusing.  (2) Ask Microsoft -- or the old Sybase developers.  They are the ones who invented and use that syntax.

Comment: You basically hit on it; SQL is not a programming language like C# is a programming language. Similarly, stored procedures are NOT methods, or functions like in, again, something like C#. Now SQL HAS functions (user defined or otherwise) which DO work like that (e.g. `select @dt = getdate()`). But stored procedures aren't commonly used to return a single value. Not to say they can't, but that's not really what they're there for. As was mentioned though, you can get at the return value using the funky syntax, or use `output` if you need something other than a return code.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure return value is intended to [indicate success or failure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) (zero for success and non-zero for error/warning. The syntax makes more sense with this in mind.

Use output variables or a result set to return data, or use a function instead.